# Add button disappears for subgrid when using addOnLoad

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

When I'm using the addOnLoad function in Dynamics CRM for my subgrid(incidents) the add button disappears. My addOnLoad event works perfectly and when I click on the delete button for a row in the subgrid the add button appears again.

[image] [image]

Obviously there is a event that can be triggered? Since the add button appears when I'm clicking on the delete button. I don't have this problem on other subgrids with relationships to other entities than incidents.

```
var grid = Xrm.Page.getControl("issues");

if (grid == null) {
    setTimeout(function () { AddEventToGridRefresh(); }, 5000);
    return;
}

grid.addOnLoad(refreshNumberOfIncidents);
```

--

```
window.refreshNumberOfIncidents = function () {

Api.getIncidents(globals.getAccountId(), function (result) {

    if (result.success) {

        arrayLength = result.data.value.length;

        Xrm.Page.getControl("WebResource_Interaction").getObject().contentWindow.document.getElementById("incidents").innerHTML = arrayLength;
    }

});
```

Comment: Please include the code samples into the question.

Comment: Updated with code sample

Comment: See if you have any ribbon customizations? More context:https://stackoverflow.com/q/45603397/7920473

Comment: @ArunVinoth Don't have any ribbon customizations, grid.refresh() or Xrm.Page.data.save() won't do it for me either.

Comment: show us the code of refreshNumberOfIncidents

Comment: @ArunVinoth Here you go

Comment: this should work. probably you have to debug it or try catch.. not sure if this assignment to iframe control break the crm form load flow.. :( any errors you see in browser console?

Comment: @ArunVinoth Getting lots of these messages "Refused to set unsafe global.ashx?ver=359582084:4020 Refused to set unsafe header "Content-Length". But I get them without the "addOnLoad" as well.

Comment: @ArunVinoth Found a solution, I had to delay the refresh like this  setTimeout(function () { Xrm.Page.data.refresh(); }, 1000);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by delaying a refresh after the addOnLoad call

```
setTimeout(function () { Xrm.Page.data.refresh(); }, 1000);
```